# Thought I tracked down what is dynamically changing a field label but still happening

Tags: entities

I am doing some work on a site that has had many hands in it. On it there is an add node which has multiple fields. When you select one option from the first dropdown, it will change the label for another field. I am looking to remove this behaviour.

The documentation said it was done in the module that was created by a long gone company. They made their own module called Intranet Base. Inside, this chunk of code looks like it is doing the work of changing the label:

```
function intranet_base_preprocess_field (&$variables) {
if ($variables['element']['#field_name'] == 'field_booking_contact')
    { 
        if ($variables['element']['#object']->type == 'calendar_room_bookings')
        {
            if ($variables['element']['#object']->field_booking_type['und'][0]['tid'] == 228)
            { 
            $variables['label'] = 'Proctor';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Removing this code does not change the behaviour on the site. I have, obviously, cleared the cache a few times. But, if I leave the function in and make a mistake on purpose, the website throws an error on that line, so it appears to be reading the file correctly. I also tried:

- different users
- different browsers

So, I figured some module must be controlling it. I looked up methods people have used before to accomplish this, but I could not find any other methods, even using this modules that are installed.

- Conditional Fields
- Rules
- Triggers
- Display Suite
- Automatic Entity Labels

I have also check the js and css folder for the theme in use.

Is there someway I can track this down? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using grep or some other similar functionality to search your site for the text "Proctor"? Maybe there are multiple hooks changing the label?

Comment: That would have been smart...
I ran a grep on the whole folder and only found the instance I already knew of. At least this narrows it down to a Drupal thing. Thanks!